# Comparing two unequal data frame and selecting common values in the order of second data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frame as follows:

```
df1<-data.frame(st=c(1,2,3,4),v1=c(12,14,15,75),v2=c(43,32,12,18))

df1
  st v1 v2
1  1 12 43
2  2 14 32
3  3 15 12
4  4 75 18

df2<-data.frame(st=c(1,2,3,4),v1=c(12,24,35,18),v2=c(48,32,121,82),v3=c(53,11,12,75))

df2
  st v1  v2 v3
1  1 12  48 53
2  2 24  32 11
3  3 35 121 12
4  4 18  82 75
```

What i want is to match both the data frame at a "st" column level i.e. for st = 1 in df1 the corresponding values for v1 and v2 are 12 & 43. So if for st= 1 in df2 if any of the variables contain these values then I want to select st, and those values from df2.

So for the above example the output will be

```
St values
1     12(coming from v1 in df2)
2     32(coming from v2 in df2)
3     12(coming from v3 in df2)
4     18 75(coming from v1 & v3 in df2)
```

The important thing to note is, in the output data frame the order of selected variables should be as that of df2, as you can see that for st = 4, the values in df1 are 75 & 18 which matches with st = 2 but still the output is 18 and then 75 which is the order in df2. Also the variables in df2 will always be greater than df1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly...

**Step 0. prepare data**

You mentioned that you only want to select rows that fit your conditions, but the sample dataset has at least one match in each row. I tweaked it such that there's no match for St=3, to demonstrate the that the row will not be returned in the result.

```
df1<-data.frame(st=c(1,2,3,4),v1=c(12,14,15,75),v2=c(43,32,12,18))
df2<-data.frame(st=c(1,2,3,4),v1=c(12,24,35,18),v2=c(48,32,121,82),v3=c(53,11,13,75))
```

**Step 1. combine the datasets**

```
combined.df <- rbind(df1 %>% gather(v, n, -st) %>% mutate(df = "df1"),
                     df2 %>% gather(v, n, -st) %>% mutate(df = "df2"))

> head(combined.df)
  st  v  n  df
1  1 v1 12 df1
2  2 v1 14 df1
3  3 v1 15 df1
4  4 v1 75 df1
5  1 v2 43 df1
6  2 v2 32 df1
```

Step 2. compare & keep only matched ones from df2

```
res <- combined.df %>%
  group_by(st) %>%
  mutate(n = ifelse(df=="df1", n, ifelse(n %in% n[df=="df1"], n, NA))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(df=="df2", !is.na(n)) %>%
  arrange(st, v)
# if you just want the values, you can stop here.
> res
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     st     v     n    df
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1     1    v1    12   df2
2     2    v2    32   df2
3     4    v1    18   df2
4     4    v3    75   df2


# this part formats the result to follow that of the desired output
res <- res %>%
  group_by(st) %>%
  summarise(values = paste(as.character(n), collapse = " ")) %>%
  ungroup()
> res
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     st values
  <dbl>  <chr>
1     1     12
2     2     32
3     4  18 75
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use merge function, you can create a unique df with this matches:

```
new<-merge(df1,df2,by="st")

new

  st v1.x v2.x v1.y v2.y v3
1  1   12   43   12   48 53
2  2   14   32   24   32 11
3  3   15   12   35  121 12
4  4   75   18   18   82 75
```

And if you want, you then can order it in the way you want. For example:

```
new2<-new[,1:2]
new2$from<-"from v1"
names(new2)<-c("st","value","from")


for(i in 3:ncol(new)){
new3<-new[,c(1,i)]
new3$from<-pasteo("from v",i)
names(new3)<-c("st","value","from")
new2<-rbind(new2,new3)

}
```

This is not the most efficient way, but if you have few data, it will work